# Ruby on rails: is there any gem/plugin which helps to switch between multiple SMS gateways

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sms-gateway

I am looking for any gem or plugin which will help in switching between multiple sms gateways.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the gem **action_sms** which can be used to switch between the different SMS_gateway providers, by writing adapter for the gateway provider.
Its pretty straight forward to implement adapters example is also given in the gem's readme file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly which SMS services you are using but

[SMS on Rails By:Girish Anand and Laksh](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/smsonrails)

have one that can connect to both Email Gateway and Clickatell. Perhaps you can extend that code to suit your needs.

Hope this helps! ;)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.
What I am looking for is, without changing code to send SMS i should be able to able to switch to different service providers whenever required.
e.g. If currently I am using clickatell to send SMS i should be able to switch to SMSCountry or some other provider with minimal changes in the code and also it would be greate if that code is plugable.
like diff. database adapters can be used with active-record.
Any sugestions for this would be greate help.